# Import Confluence xml dump into Mediawiki

Tags: xml, mediawiki, porting, sample, confluence

Is it possible to import a Confluence xml dump into Mediawiki? If so, any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks for you assistance!

Comment: could you clarify on the Confluence bit?? what is it?

Comment: Confluence is another wiki software tool. http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview. We are looking to migrate to MediaWiki (server related issues). Thanks

Comment: Did you made any progress on this or choosed another solution? I ended up considering the same option after a failed upgrade to Confluence 5 (from 3) which annoyed people due to the losing the wiki syntax and due to the system instability. Surprise, we discovered that there are no performance tests for the latest Confluence as Atlassian decided to  change them one year ago but nothing was released in between. So, as a customer you may end-up in a very difficult situation because it is very hard to test the (in)stability of Confluence.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a converter from Confluence to Twiki:

http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/ConfluenceToTWikiAddOn

and converters from Twiki to MediaWiki:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Twiki

Here are a few markup translation tools:

- [Confluence to MediaWiki Converter](http://www.infinality.net/files/confluence-to-mediawiki-converter/)
- [Wikifier](http://www.amnet.net.au/~ghannington/confluence/wikifier/)
- [Doxia](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/doxia-tools/doxia-converter/index.html)
- [Mylyn](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Incubator/WikiText)

Comment: Those are pretty much worthless - they just convert / translate markup. Question is about importing a full Confluence Dump (containing all Spaces, Pages, Attachments, ...)

Comment: @BozoJoe, honestly I don't really memember participating on this question. I've gained some experience migrating from one Confluence instance to another, including manual pre and postmigration tasks, but I haven't exported Confluence data to any other application...

Answer (score 0):

Still working on if this is a solution or not, but....

1. from confluence export the space, as HTML
2. then using https://github.com/svick/LINQ-to-Wiki
3. spider from the created index.html page from the confluence export
4. and insert new pages into MediaWiki

god help me if this works (I despise mediawiki)

Comment: nah - total waste of time.  I even started to fix up the github project, but it burned up in my hands.   SOLUTION:  got one of the interns to manually cut and paste everything.

Answer (score 0):

Rather old question, but for whoever might be looking for something similar you can try:

https://github.com/hallowelt/migrate-confluence