# Importing a confluence xml/html dump into mediawiki

Tags: php, html, xml, mediawiki, confluence

I am trying to import a 150 MB dump into mediawiki. It is too large for the Special:Import method. And i also think it has to be converted somehow, because when I'm trying to import it with importDump.php I get the message "expected  tag, but got . I tried changing the tag in the XML file manually, and then i get a success-message but nothing gets imported.

I also tried importing the html dump it with mwimporter (http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/mwimporter/index.html), and it imports all the pages, but no attachments. Oh, and it also doesn't correctly display some tables, because they're written in the confluence-markup, but that's not that much of an issue, but I really need those attachments.

Any ideas on how to import it correctly?

EDIT: I did not find a solution for the MediaWiki-Import. A year later i had to do a wiki to confluence migration and the [Universal Wiki Converter (UWC)](https://migrations.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/UWC/overview?mode=global) was a good tool for exporting and importing.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581445/import-confluence-xml-dump-into-mediawiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap up: For anyone facing a similar problem, I'd suggest looking into the [Universal Wiki Converter (UWC)](https://migrations.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/UWC/overview?mode=global) from Atlassian. Though I haven't solved this specific problem, I was able to do a wiki-migration to confluence using this tool.

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of Confluence XML files, but for more verbose output of the importDump.php maintenance script, add the --debug option.  You can find it described here:  [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aImporting_XML_dumps)

That will at least tell you more about what's going wrong.